# Finding the Max of Excel Matrix Data based on Criteria from Maxtrix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data on Matrix and I also have the criteria data in Matrix as well See below

Data from the Matrix

| Period | 0.0 | 30 | 45 | 60 | 75 | 90 | 105 | 120 | 135 | 150 | 180 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.0 | 0.356 | 0.443 | 0.469 | 0.505 | 0.579 | 0.525 | 0.516 | 0.475 | 0.342 | 0.271 | 0.171 |
| 7.0 | 0.439 | 0.541 | 0.558 | 0.678 | 0.802 | 0.642 | 0.747 | 0.499 | 0.436 | 0.336 | 0.232 |
| 8.0 | 0.505 | 0.544 | 0.591 | 0.694 | 0.759 | 0.747 | 0.736 | 0.584 | 0.560 | 0.467 | 0.269 |
| 9.0 | 0.489 | 0.614 | 0.618 | 0.630 | 0.791 | 0.687 | 0.631 | 0.577 | 0.507 | 0.562 | 0.340 |
| 10.0 | 0.538 | 0.603 | 0.572 | 0.580 | 0.703 | 0.643 | 0.619 | 0.556 | 0.489 | 0.459 | 0.399 |
| 11.0 | 0.503 | 0.491 | 0.513 | 0.578 | 0.585 | 0.630 | 0.587 | 0.542 | 0.439 | 0.459 | 0.345 |
| 12.0 | 0.517 | 0.446 | 0.539 | 0.588 | 0.546 | 0.564 | 0.552 | 0.497 | 0.411 | 0.412 | 0.355 |
| 13.0 | 0.470 | 0.439 | 0.545 | 0.534 | 0.530 | 0.482 | 0.510 | 0.470 | 0.422 | 0.404 | 0.329 |
| 14.0 | 0.399 | 0.427 | 0.469 | 0.442 | 0.462 | 0.434 | 0.409 | 0.425 | 0.382 | 0.395 | 0.340 |
| 15.0 | 0.370 | 0.390 | 0.388 | 0.397 | 0.421 | 0.393 | 0.355 | 0.387 | 0.355 | 0.341 | 0.331 |

Criteria for the matrix

| Period | 0.0 | 30 | 45 | 60 | 75 | 90 | 105 | 120 | 135 | 150 | 180 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6.0 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 7.0 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 10 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 8.0 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 10 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 5 | 2 |
| 9.0 | 6 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 7 | 3 |
| 10.0 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| 11.0 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 12.0 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 13.0 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 14.0 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 15.0 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Is there any way to find the maximum of no 3 or 10 from the criteria data on the criteria Matrix, and the max values should be taken the matrix data based on the location from the matrix criteria ?

So from the above No 10 should be the maximum from Matrix ( [7,75] or [7,105] or [8,75] or [8,90] or [9,75] )?

I am expecting Excel function or VBA to find the max data of those numbers?
Thanks alot for your help and taught about it

Excel Function or Excel VBA

Answer (score 0):

Assume tables start (with header row and column) in cell A1 of two sheets named Criteria and Data:

`=MAX(SUMPRODUCT( (Criteria!B2:L11=10) * (Data!B2:L11) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

### Max in Matrix Using Criteria Matrix

**Edit**

- By using dynamic array functions, you can create a single spilling formula:

```
=LET(tCriteria,B2:L11,tData,Data!B2:L11,Criteria,N2:N12,
    BYROW(Criteria,LAMBDA(cRow,
MAX(TOCOL((tCriteria=cRow)*tData)))))
```

**Old**

- If you have Microsoft 365 and if the criteria are in the range `N2:N12`, in cell `O2` of sheet `Criteria` you could use:

  ```
  =MAX(TOCOL(($B$2:$L$11=N2)*Data!$B$2:$L$11))
  ```

  or (more of the same i.e. getting familiar with the LET function)

  ```
  =LET(tCriteria,$B$2:$L$11,tData,Data!$B$2:$L$11,Criteria,N2,
      MAX(TOCOL((tCriteria=Criteria)*tData)))
  ```

  used in cell `P2` of the screenshot, and copy down.

[image]
[image]